# motionEvents didn't work Android Java

Tags: java, android, motionevent

i can't get message in Logcat from  events : **MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE** and **MotionEvent.ACTION_UP**. I couldn't find solution for it so i ask it here.

I have this overrided method in my class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.d("action","Action was MOVE");
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d("action","Action was DOWN");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.d("action","Action was UP");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

And in LogCat i can see just message from 
**MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN** : "action" "Action was DOWN" . No messages from other actions.

I try it in my phone and in AVD.

Thanks for any response.

**Answer:**
return must be set to **true** and not for super constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Set return to **True** and not for super constructor :)